# How do I get real-time position of finger as it moves from left to right?

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I'm really struggling on an Android app in Phonegap and JQuery.

All I want to do is, as I drag my finger from left to right, I want to be able to output to screen exactly what my x position is.

I can't use touchmove as that simply gives me the coordinates at the end of the movement, I need the real-time coordinates?

Are there any JQuery plugins I could use?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
text = document.getElementById('element to hold text'); // element that can write the x position

document.getElementById('element').ontouchmove = function (e) 
{e.preventDefault(); 
e.stopPropagation();
text.innerHTML = e.touches[0].clientX; //set the inner html of the text element to be the x position of the touch
};
```

Answer (score -2):

First you say appp then you say jquery ??

How is that possible ??

Anyways in case of app you can use

```
OnTouchListener
```

And for web you can use

> MouseMove event (or)
>
> click Event

All three methods would have postion as params

Comment: You can use JQuery when developing apps using Phonegap. Detecting a touch is straightforward. Touchmove only provides the end points of the movement, not the current position - which is what I want.

Comment: View.OnTouchListener does what you are asking for.

Comment: But how is that intergrated into PhoneGap?